# Where did utils.php come from, TinyMCE hack

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Last Wednesday a variety of the WordPress sites I manage got hacked, they were infected with a Viagra link (malware is so original).

I noticed in the wp-includes directory a file called utils.php (wp-includes/js/tinymce/utils/utils.php), also an addition to my general-template.php for the get_footer function.

This hack seems to only affect Google search results for sites, not the site when directly viewed by entering the URL, i.e your cached site will show a malware infested mess and lose ranking, meanwhile you will wonder why due to the site looking fine when viewed.

My host (TSO Host) have cleaned up the sites, didn't even need to ask, but I have no idea how the infection got there in the first place.

So my question is, does anyone know how the breach happens and what I can do to prevent it, other than the usual security tips?

Comment: Didn't your hosting company said anything about that? They should have logs of the server access and activity and should in theory be able to trace down the infection. I would recommend two plugins - [Bulletproof Security](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bulletproof-security/) and [Wordfence](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordfence/). I'm pretty sure there are other good security plugins out-there, but these two seem like a good combination.

Comment: I'm just wondering if people know specifically how the hack occurs, the process of it because I write the security doc which other employees follow for WordPress installs, the information from the host wasn't very useful other than a list of the changed files.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to a site that I spent weeks cleaning up. I can give you a few pointers:

- Go through the Wordpress core files (under wp-admin and wp-includes) and delete all files that you don't see in the default wordpress instillation. I've never seen a plugin create a file in one of those 2 directories. After this, it'd be a good idea to re-install Wordpress, just in case they changed any of the existing files.
- After that, change your Wordpress/FTP/SSH passwords as they've likly been cracked. Install [WP Better Security](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/). It seems a little annoying at first, but you can monitor *everything* with it, change the login slug, remove version info hackers can use to find security holes, black-list known hackers, and so much more.
- Finally, this last one will take some time. Google your theme and each one of your plugins, and see if Wordpress has stopped using them because they were a security vulnerability. You'd be surprised at how many plugins haves holes. Try to avoid really new plugins, and try to use the same plugin for as many different sites as you can. If you're hosting more than one site on the same server and one of the sites gets hacked, they're *all* hacked.

It sounds like a pain, and it is a little bit, but after you're done you'll feel so much better knowing that you're in control of everything. Trust me.